Why is consummation of a marriage when very young permissible when pregnancy at young age carries high risks and dangers?
https://shamela.ws/book/11430/18980#p1
This link talks about the following:

The Malikis and Shafi'is say that when a minor is able to withstand intercourse this impediment is removed.

The Shafi'is say that if the husband says 'hand her over to me and I will not have intercourse until she is able' even then she will not be handed over to him, even if he is trustworthy. That is because there is no reasonable security from his lust.


Medical research discourages pregnancy at very young ages e.g. 9, 10 and 11. However, Aisha was married at 9, an age considered very young for pregnancy. Scholars tend to focus on the dangers of sexual intercourse rather than pregnancy itself. How can coitus be permissible with a very young girl but the dangers pregnancy  which can follow, were not discussed by them?
Regarding the marriage to Aisha, since we have more medical knowledge of the dangers of very young pregnancy, would marrying someone of that very young age be forbidden and objectively wrong today, since the shafis said if you fear harm for her then the hand over cannot happen? I'm asking as angel Gabriel essentially passed the message to marry her from God.
I have seen related Qs on the site but this is a bit different.
Thanks.

Thanks umH for sharing that, however, studies show that there is 4X greater maternal mortality for women 10-14 yrs old. This still seems contrary the above scholars when they say consummation can occur when the girl can stand coitus (which could be 12). But scholars never spoke of the danger of pregnancy which could result from it. Does this mean minor marriage and consummation is permissible despite the very high risk?

I think video might debunk the claims made by medical scientist
Dr Abdullah has debunked each points of so-called harm in detail in the post-debate analysis podcast with Daniel haqiqatjoue related to early marriage
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEeZqIyKKgg&pp=ygUVbXVzbGltIHNrZXB0aWMgZG9jdG9y

Hi. Thanks for sharing. I will check out the video soon.

Check it they debunked all the claims. These claims of harms are usually political in nature and stats by United Nations are usually from improvised nations which are either in war zone or financial crisis in health sector. They also explained that

Thanks once again. But surely there is some truth to coitus at a very young age right being risky right? If she gets pregnant when the pelvic is not wide enough due to her young age it could be serious, but scholars never discussed the harm from pregnancy but just the harm from coitus itself?

There are females in medical history who given birth without C-section and anesthesia. Secondly, 2003 I think it was a Thailand english newspaper which had case of 9 year old delivering a baby it was only relieved when her husband applied for birth certificate because her wife from no angle was seen young meaning she had body of young women. Imam Bayhaqi saw a girl in Sanaa, yemen who was grandmother at age of 21 her daughter and she gave birth age of 10 as per report

Thank you for your help
